# Random topological sorting with uniform distribution in near linear time

Tags: algorithm, random, topological-sort, uniform-distribution

I want an algorithm for topological sorting that doesn't provide the same sorting each time, but a random one, each sorting being equally likely to all others.

Generating all possible topological sortings and picking one at random is correct, but far too slow. Generating all permutations and filtering the invalid topological sorts is also very slow; the first one degrades into the second one if the tree/forest is wide enough.

Inserting new nodes into a random position in the queue of nodes to be checked seems like it would produce a biased result, and putting it at the end and doing a fisher-yates shuffle also seems biased, since both fail to account for the number of nodes "hidden" under each node, i.e. how many nodes depend on `a` or `b` being scheduled. `a` could have no children, while `b` holds the rest of the tree.

How can I generate a random topological sorting with each valid sorting being equally likely, in near-linear time?

Comment: Relevant, but not dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11420191/random-algorithm-over-all-topological-sorts-of-a-dag

Answer (score 1):

**Edit:** Solving this problem the way you want to is not possible in any reasonable amount of time. To do so involves solving a #P-complete problem. Your best bet is to use a probabilistic approach.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45875/how-can-you-compute-the-number-of-topological-sorts-in-a-dag

1. Come up with a list of all edges
2. Determine which nodes are "start" nodes. Start nodes have no directed edges coming into them
3. For each start node, pick it, remove all the directed edges that correspond to it, then consider the number of possible next moves. Once you find the number of possible moves for every start node, pick a node randomly based on its probability (an example is given below).
4. Remove the edges the start node points to.
5. Repeat steps 2 through 4.

This is similar to Kahn's algorithm.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting#Kahn.27s_algorithm

As long as you are picking each start node randomly from all other start nodes, you should get a random valid topological sort that has the same probability as any other random topological sort.

For instance, if I have a graph {(5, 11)(7, 8)(7, 11)(3, 8)(3, 10)(8, 9)(11, 2)(11, 9)(11, 10)} where (a, b) is a directed edge from a to b, I would first determine that 5, 7, and 3 are start nodes. I would randomly pick one (3), then remove all edges starting with 3, which includes (3,8) and (3, 10). I would check if nodes 8 and 10 are now start nodes. They are not. My start nodes are now 5 and 7. I would pick another random start node (7), and then remove all edges with 7, which are (7, 8) and (7, 11). I would check if any of these are start nodes. 8 is a start node. My start nodes are now 5 and 8. I randomly pick 8, remove edges with 8, which includes (8, 9). I check if 9 is a start node. My only start node is 5. I pick 5, remove edges (5, 11). 11 is now my only start node. I pick 11, remove edges (11, 2), (11, 9), and (11, 10). 2, 9, and 10 are now start nodes. I pick 2 randomly, remove all edges. 9 and 10 are my start nodes. I pick 10, then 9.

My topological sort is now {3, 7, 8, 5 11, 2, 10, 9}

**Edit:** It appears that finding the number of valid topological sorts is #P-complete, which means that your best bet is to use a probabilistic algorithm to determine the number of possible sorts for each element, then adjust the probability based on the total number of topological sorts of all the start nodes.

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/45875/how-can-you-compute-the-number-of-topological-sorts-in-a-dag

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sharp-P-complete

**Edit:** You could guess the fraction of topological sorts starting with a specific start node by choosing that start node, removing all the directed edges going from it, then calculating the number of all possible next moves, and then finding a good function to model it. For instance, in my example, if I picked 5, I would have two possible moves next, 3 and 7. If I picked 3 or 7, I would also have two possible moves left. I would then find out what fraction of possible moves I have left, then pick one probabilistically. In this case, all three have equal chances, so then I just pick one randomly. In this case, I pick 3. I then can pick either 5 or 7. If I pick 5, I will only have one possible move left, 7, and if I pick 7, I would have two possible moves left. 7 therefore has a 2/3 chance of being picked and 5 has a 1/3 chance. This process continues until you reach the end. This is only a heuristic, but it should get you a good approximation of picking a completely random valid topological sort. Also, in the counterexample you gave, adding one to the number of possible moves for each start node seemed to get a better approximation.

Comment: This doesn't make each possible sorting equally likely.  The chance of picking X as the first node needs to be proportional to the number of valid orderings that start with X.

Comment: @Filip Haglund Could you specify the notation you are using? Because it looks like you have to choose 2 first or else you cannot pick 3 based on your first edge.

Comment: Had a typo. Counter-example: `2->4`, `3->4`, `3->5`. The first choice is `2` or `3` which partitions all possible topo-sorts unevenly. `2` first leaves us unable to choose `5` next, but if we pick `3` first, we can pick `2`, `4` or `5` next.

Comment: @Filip Haglund The first thing is that you need to pick both 2 and 3 to pick 4. Secondly, all the possible topological sorts in the counterexample are {2,3,4,5};{2,3,5,4};{3,5,2,4};{3,2,4,5};{3,2,5,4}. The random algorithm I set up will randomly pick 2 or 3, as they are start nodes. If it picks 2, then it can only pick 3 as 4 and 5 are dependent on 3. Once it picks 3, it can pick the other two in any order. If it picked 3 first, it can pick either 2 or 5. If it picks 2 next, it can either pick 4 or 5. If it picked 5 instead of 2, it must pick 2 first because 4 depends on 2.

Comment: @Matt Timmermans Good point. This only really generates a random valid topological sort with uneven probability.

Comment: @Filip Haglund I figured out what you meant and where I went wrong. Sorry about that.

Comment: You're right @AlgorithmsX I missed the `2->4` relation when enumerating the possible orderings. I was trying to highlight the uneven distribution. The `3524` path is twice as likely as the `3254` path, since the latter forks with the `3245` path. This somehow has to be accounted for by weighting branches differently.

Comment: @Filip Haglund This looks like a much harder problem to solve than I thought. It is #P-complete.

Comment: Good answer. Since your edits are not really a refinement, but more of a fundamental change to what you first wrote, I suggest you just edit your last comment somehow into the start.

Comment: @AlgorithmsX I am still not convinced this is #P-complete. I can use the number of topological sortings for each subtree to generate a perfect uniformly distributed randomized toposort, but I do not see why this would be the only way to do it, or how a function that generates uniformly distributed random toposorts could be used to count the total number of toposorts in less than #P-time. The first two sentances of your answer are not as clear to me as they seem to be to you. A heuristics-based approach could still be the best option, though. Could you please share your reasoning?

Comment: @Filip Haglund I added my source for why I think it is #P-complete. The idea is that once you choose a node and remove all the corresponding edges, you are left with another sub-DAG. If you want to find out how may topological sorts you have starting with that node, you need to find out how many topological sorts you have in the sub-DAG. You need to find out how many topological sorts you can have with each node in order to find the probability of a topological sort starting with that node.

Comment: @Filip Haglund I added the probabalistic equivalent of a greedy algorithm as my heuristic. This should run very fast.